# How and where to buy genuine claves in La Habana?

Tags: shopping, cuba, tourist-traps, havana

My father is going to La Habana in a month or so, and I would like him to buy me a pair of claves while he is there. He is, however, no musician and would probably find difficult to choose a good pair by himself, especially as a quick web search leads me to believe that many that can be found are little more than pieces of woods for tourists.

How should he look for a seller that caters more to musicians than to tourists?

Comment: Also worth noting that asking for recommendations (last sentence) is considered off topic (see [help] for more details).

Answer (score 5):

There is a small musical instruments store in Havana, in a place called "[El Boulevard de San Rafael](https://goo.gl/maps/mlRmm)", it's a pedestrian street and the store is about 300 meters from [Hotel Inglaterra](http://www.hotelinglaterra-cuba.com/).

If you prefer, you could also post an add on the website revolico.com before traveling there (this is similar to kijiji, craigslist etc, very popular in Cuba) saying "busco claves profesionales (instrumento musical)", or [search directly for a luthier](http://www.revolico.com/search.html?q=luthier&min_price=&max_price=&order=date) on the same website:

[image]